# After finding repositories /etc/apt/sources.list and rebooting parrot, I must update

Tags: parrotsec

```
[✗] ─ [zorillo @ zorillo-virtualbox] ─ [~] └──╼ $ sudo apt-get upgrade
apt upgrade is unsafe on rolling release distributions.
using apt full-upgrade instead
use apt upgrade --force to override
E: Entry 11 incorrectly specified in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse) E: The source lists could not be read. E: Entry 11 incorrectly specified in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse) E: The source lists could not be read. E: Entry 11 incorrectly specified in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse) E: The source lists could not be read.
parrotsec
E: Entrada 11 mal especificada en list fichero /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse)
E: No se pudieron leer las listas de fuentes.
E: Entrada 11 mal especificada en list fichero /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse)
E: No se pudieron leer las listas de fuentes.
E: Entrada 11 mal especificada en list fichero /etc/apt/sources.list (URI parse)
E: No se pudieron leer las listas de fuentes.
```

Answer (score 0):

Override the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` with the correct repositories:

```
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
```

You can use the following command:

```
cat <<EOF |sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling main contrib non-free
deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
#deb-src https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot/ rolling-security main contrib non-free
EOF
```

Remove all files from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Comment: @Stewart already have it, I want the repositories of /etc/apt/sources.list I had already put them in the corrests but I gave reboot and the parrot was abandoned and I lost the repositories

Comment: @Stewart I got that that's because I need the repositories /etc/apt/sources.list                             0 actualizados, 0 nuevos se instalarán, 0 para eliminar y 2 no actualizados.

Comment: No bro... I need the repositories from /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: No bro... I need the repositories from /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: @JavierHernandez I have edited my answer. (The default sources in Parrot is under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list`)

Comment: THEN I PUT THOSE REPOSITORIES IN THE /ETC/APT/SOURCES.LIST

Comment: Done The following packages have been retained: linux-headers-amd64 linux-image-amd64 0 update, 0 new ones will be installed , 0 to remove and 2 not to update.

Comment: @JavierHernandez Do not forget to mark this answer as accepted. Please.

Comment: @DOGER OK.........